# How to apply design patterns in server-side Dart with client-side Polymer.dart?

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, dart, dart-polymer

Using Dart with Polymer.dart allows to easily implement design patterns in the style of MVC, MVP or MVVM. I suppose that in a web environment the controller part is essentially an HTTP request handler/router that calls views or models.

The question is: can you show an example on **how to connect user input data from HTML + Polymer.dart up to a database back-end?**

As far as I can see, the "two-way data binding" announced by Polymer.dart seems to relate only to client-side code.

My problem is understanding how the client-side Dart code that listens to HTML form inputs may interact with the server-side Dart code. Would that be a typical AJAX request that calls the controller or is there a more idiomatic two-way data binding that I'm missing in Dart?

Comment: Do you have a background in a particular technology so that an answer can compare it to something that you are familiar with?

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, thank you, I've been using Go, PHP and .Net in the last years without any particular framework. I think Günter already made the issue clear. Anyway, some library out there may abstract the gap between client and server sides. It's not a problem to see that the base libraries don't do that.

Comment: I agree with Günter's assessment.  These days the front end is much thicker and the server generally just serves out static html/js that is the client app, and then supports persistence via a service layer (REST or hand rolled).  There are libraries that support straight linking back to the server that have Dart wrappers.  Firebase comes to mind. https://www.firebase.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no two way data-binding between client and server in Dart (Meteor is a popular JavaScript/NodeJS framework that seems to do that). The design patterns you mentioned are pure client side. Data-binding in Dart is between the view (HTML markup) and the model (Dart code) that is holding the data for the view. The controller (or presenter or view model) is responsible to react on data changes or other user actions like pressing a button, to use a 'service' like HTTP (AJAX) to send the data to the server or fetch new data from the server.
The server processes and stores received data and/or responds with the requested data .

These patterns primary purpose is to make client code testable. 
The view (HTML) is hard to test. Using such patterns splits the view from model and controller and makes at least these two easy testable.

There is much literature out there about such design patterns. Such questions are usually to broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: I agree, it's a bit broad but perhaps also one of the main issues a new Dart developer like me will face. Now I'm seeing either too much redundancy or just good design practices... It looks like I've got to create server-side models to abstract/validate to the database side, and client-side polymer models to abstract/validate to the client-side. Thank you, Günter.

Comment: You can search pub.dartlang.org for 'model' there are some open source projects in the works but I didn't yet try one of these myself.